# Database options with raw SQL querying capabilities for WP8

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, windows-phone-8

I would like to use an existing set of **raw SQL statements** to store adata and perform data manipulation on a **Windows Phone 8** device.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that **LINQ to SQL** does not provide a way to execute raw SQL statements. Because of this, it complicates my task of simply delegating SQL statements to the query engine to writing a complex framework which would translate raw SQL statements to Linq to SQL syntax.

Under the hood, LINQ to SQL uses an `sdf` database file format, and that is an **SQL Server Compact 4.0** database I presume. Is there a way to access, say, `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace from WP8 app to directly manipulate data in the database file?

Is my only feasible option using **SQLite for WP8** which, people say, is very slow compared to SQL Server Compact on WP8?

Comment: "Correct me if I'm wrong" - I don't think you are wrong; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_LINQtoSQLRuntime - "A local database can be accessed only with LINQ to SQL; Transact-SQL is not supported."

Comment: Thanks. I Should have mentioned that link. On that sentence I based my assumption from the second paragraph (but you can't trust one msdn page one hundred percent, can you?).